# Using PowerShell to execute a SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have some SQL statements that are being used to create stored procedures.

I have no access to the SQL Server itself, and none of the client tools have been installed. All that I can use is the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`.

I have put together the following PowerShell script which reads the query to execute from a text file.

```bsh
$sqltoexecute = Get-Content(".\script_to_execute.sql");
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionstring
$connection.Open()
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.Connection = $connection
$command.CommandText = $sqltoexecute 
$command.CommandTimeout = 0
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However when trying to execute the following highly abbreviated SQL statement

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Upsert_TaxonEntityFields] @EntityFieldsXml XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @entityFieldDefs TABLE(
            Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
            Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            IsLanguageInvariant BIT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (Id));

        DECLARE @entityFieldValues TABLE(
            TaxonId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
            FieldId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            LanguageCode NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
            FieldValue NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (TaxonId, FieldId, LanguageCode));
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @error_number INTEGER = ERROR_NUMBER()
        DECLARE @error_severity INTEGER = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        DECLARE @error_state INTEGER = ERROR_STATE()
        DECLARE @error_message NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        DECLARE @error_procedure SYSNAME = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        DECLARE @error_line INTEGER = ERROR_LINE()

        RAISERROR( N'T-SQL ERROR %d, SEVERITY %d, STATE %d, PROCEDURE %s, LINE %d, MESSAGE: %s', @error_severity, 1, @error_number, @error_severity, @error_state, @error_procedure, @error_line, @error_message ) WITH NOWAIT

    END CATCH
END
```

However, when I execute it, I am receiving the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

If I remove the semicolons, then I get error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Now I am stumpted. Running the SQL in SSMS (on a test environment), then it runs without problems.

Are you able to create objects in SQL Server from PowerShell?

Comment: Why aren't you using sqlcmd or at least SQL Server's powershell provider? You are using ADO.NET objects which are used for *querying*, not scripting.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I have to run this from a SQL that does not have the SQL server tools installed. there is no sqlcmd, and as far as I can tell, the SQL server powershell tools also require the SQL server binaries. Hence the only option available to me is ado.net objects

Comment: Just [download the command line tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52680), it's only a 2MB download. Executing scripts is a job for SMO anyway, it allows you to use the same scripting commands as SSMS, like GO

Comment: Might be something really trivial. Try `$sqltoexecute = Get-Content ".\script_to_execute.sql" | Out-String`.

Comment: i have tested your script on my pc, not problem. May be check you connexionstring